# Проблема с сервером на сокетах(Python)

Tags: python, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер

Я решил разобраться с библиотекой socket и асинхронностью, для подключения использовал и cURL и своего клиента(тоже написанного на сокетах), при подключение выскакивает данная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\piple\Desktop\Курс по пайтну\test_server_python\1_select.py", line 42, in 
<module>
event_loop()
File "C:\Users\piple\Desktop\Курс по пайтну\test_server_python\1_select.py", line 38, in 
event_loop
send_message(sock)
File "C:\Users\piple\Desktop\Курс по пайтну\test_server_python\1_select.py", line 22, in 
send_message
request = client_socket.recv(4096)
OSError: [WinError 10057] Запрос на отправку или получение данных  (when sending on a datagram 
socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Я долго искал в гугле эту ошибку, но так и не нашёл решение своей ошибки, надеюсь на вашу помощь. Вот мой код:

````
import socket
from select import select

to_monitor = []

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4242))
server_sock.listen()

print("ОСНОВНЫЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ СОЗДАНЫ")
def accept_connection(server_sock):
    client_socket, addr = server_sock.accept()
    print('Входящее подключение c адреса: ', addr)
    
    to_monitor.append(client_socket)
    print('TO_MONITOR(ACCEPT): ')

def send_message(client_socket):
    
    request = client_socket.recv(4096)
    if request:
        response = 'Hello world \n'.encode()
        client_socket.send(response)
    else:
        client_socket.close()


def event_loop():
    while True:
        
        ready_to_read, _, _ = select(to_monitor, [], []) # read, write, errors
        for sock in ready_to_read:
            if sock is server_sock:
                accept_connection(sock)
            else:
                send_message(sock)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    to_monitor.append(server_sock)
    event_loop()```
````

Comment: У вас `else` находится на уровне цикла `for` и поэтому ведёт себя не так, как вы планировали

Comment: @andreymal так в питоне у for тоже есть else, только в данном случае без break нет смысла в нём

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, но теперь выскочила другая ошибка... ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\piple\Desktop\Курс по пайтну\test_server_python\1_select.py", line 42, in <module>
    event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\piple\Desktop\Курс по пайтну\test_server_python\1_select.py", line 33, in event_loop
    ready_to_read, _, _ = select(to_monitor, [], []) # read, write, errors
ValueError: file descriptor cannot be a negative integer (-1)```